# Подчёт количество одинаковых данных в таблице mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подчёт количество одинаковых данных в таблице mysql

Comment: А вопрос то в чём? И причём тут вообще php?

Comment: Нужно показывать сколко кликов home, portal, bic

Comment: Вопрос касается исключительно sql. Пробовали смотреть документацию? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp Примените подобный запрос на предложенный вариант ответа от user190134.

Comment: `одинаковых данных` - что должно быть одинаковым?

Comment: Нужно привести пример имеющихся в таблице данных и результата. Из описания неясно.

Answer (score 1):

Группируем по полю click , добавляем `COUNT()` получаем стату:

```
SELECT A.click , COUNT(*) count_click FROM table A GROUP BY A.click
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `table` WHERE `click` = 'bic';
```